# htaccess redirect all old ids to new

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have general knowledge of htaccess. I can rewrite old urls to new...etc. I rebuilt the site and have new URLs with slug etc.. something i did not have before. I have about 4000 urls indexed by search engines.

These current URLs are like so: 
domain/records.php?id=44

My new site URLs are like so: 
domain/record-44-name-of-record

I can redirect each one individually with success with the following code in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=44
RewriteRule ^records\.php /record-44-name-of-record? [R=301]
```

While the above works perfect. I don't want to manually write 4000 urls in my htaccess. I've tried many different ways based off of what i search here and google without luck.

Comment: From where will you get `name-of-record` in new URL?

Comment: from my sequel table called record name then slug within php.